# Why am I not getting output when I run the following assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64

I am required to use x86 64 bit intel

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, "hello"
mov rdx, 5
syscall

mov rax, 60
xor rdi, rdi
syscall
```

I was hoping for hello to print in the terminal. Thanks for any assistance

Comment: `mov rsi, "hello"` doesn't do what you think it does. You need to place your string into memory and load its address. E.g. `lea rsi, [rel hello]` and put `hello: db "hello"` at the end of your file (optionally into a separate section, but read-only constant is fine in `.text` as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction `mov rsi, "hello"` is not valid for what you want to do. If you look at the code generated by such a beast, you see:

```
00000010  48 BE 68 65 6C 6C 6F 00 00 00  mov rsi, "hello"
```

The `48BE` is an immediate load of `rsi` and it's using the ***ASCII*** values of the characters in `hello` (padded with zeros) to form the address (`68 = 'h'`, `65 = 'e'`, `6c = 'l'`, and `6f = 'o'`). This memory address is *very* unlikely to hold anything useful *at all*, let alone the characters of the word you want to print.

---

Instead, you should define some memory to hold the string then load `rsi` with the address of that, something like the following:

```
section .text
global _start

_hello:     db "hello", 10
_hello_sz:  equ $ - _hello

_start:     mov rax, 1
            mov rdi, 1
            mov rsi, _hello
            mov rdx, _hello_sz
            syscall

            mov rax, 60
            xor rdi, rdi
            syscall
```

Compiling and running this results in the following:

```bash
pax@hades-1> nasm -f elf64 -o progs.o progs.s
pax@hades-1> ld -o progs progs.o
pax@hades-1> ./progs
hello
```

---

You'll notice I've *calculated* the length of the string using a formula, allowing you to change it without worrying about ensuring the length is updated to match, such as adding a newline character `10` for nicer output :-)

I've also not worried about putting the string into a separate data segment since, as a constant, it can stay in the code segment without issue. However, should you wish to do that, see the example below:

```
section .rodata

_hello:         db "hello", 10
_hello_sz:      equ $ - _hello

section .text
global _start

_start:         mov rax, 1
                :
                and so on.
```